# wlan printer samsung 2835 - IP address?

Tags: wireless, samsung

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and try to integrate a samsung printer into a wlan network.

I am able to print via an usb connection but I am not able to identify the printer in my wlan-network. I am not able to get the MAC address or IP address.

In the manuals one can read that you might press the wps button (or the x button) of the printer to get ipadress and login data of the printer. This method does not work in my case. My wlan router does not have a wps button. And this method works only if you have a wps button at your router.

Can anybody give some instructions how to proceed? 
Thanks 
Hermann

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clarify, a wireless device does not have an IP, if it's not connected to a network (which is why you can't identify it).

Now, [the mannual provides the SyncThru™ Web Service](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201507/20150731114246659/EN/English/English/manual/BABBHHBB.htm#CHDHHEDC?isTocLink=fixed), and the steps are as follows:

> Check whether or not the network cable is connected to the machine. If not, connect the machine with a standard network cable.
>
> Start a web browser such as Internet Explorer, Safari, or Firefox and
>   enter your machine’s new IP address in the browser window.
>
> For example, 192.168.1.133
>
> Click Login on the upper right of the SyncThru™ Web Service website.
>
> Type in the ID and Password then click Login. We recommend you to
>   change the default password for security reasons.
>
> ```
> ID:  admin
>
> Password:  sec00000
> ```
>
> When the SyncThru™ Web Service window opens, click Network Settings.
>
> Click Wireless > Wizard. [Note]
>
> Wizard will help you setup the wireless network configuration.
>   However, if you want to set the wireless network directly, select
>   Custom.
>
> Select the one Network Name(SSID) in the list.
>
> ```
> SSID: SSID (Service Set Identifier) is a name that identifies a wireless network, access points, and wireless devices attempting to
> ```
>
> connect to a specific wireless network must use the same SSID. The
>   SSID is case sensitive.
>
> ```
> Operation Mode: Operation Mode refers to the type of wireless connections (see Wireless network name and network password).
>
>     Ad-hoc: Allows wireless devices to communicate directly with each other in a peer-to-peer environment.
>
>     Infrastructure: Allows wireless devices to communicate with each other through an access point.
> ```
>
> [Note]
>
> If your network’s Operation Mode is Infrastructure, select the SSID of
>   the access point. If the Operation Mode is Ad-hoc, select the
>   machine’s SSID.
>
> Click Next.
>
> If the wireless security setting window appears, enter the registered
>   password (network password) and click Next.
>
> The confirmation window appears, please check your wireless setup. If
>   the setup is right, click Apply. [Caution]
>
> Disconnect the network cable (standard or network). Your machine
>   should then start communicating wirelessly with the network. In case
>   of Ad-hoc mode, you can use a wireless LAN and wired LAN
>   simultaneously.

Insert the supplied software CD into your CD-ROM drive, and follow the instructions in the window to set up the wireless network.